# Is it correct and natural to say "share one's mobile data with someone via one's hotspot"?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me it is correct and natural to say *share one's mobile data with someone via one's hotspot*? For example:

> If you've run out of your data allowance, I can **share my data with your via my hotspot**.

If sounds unnatural, would you please tell how you  would phrase it.

Comment: What you are sharing is your data allowance, not your data. "share my data" sounds like you are giving the person your contact details, bank accoun number, vital statistics....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said isn't wrong, it just sounds a little formal to me. Like something out of an instruction manual. Instead, I would say:

- If you've run out of your data allowance, I can share my hotspot with you.
- If you've run out of your data allowance, you can share my hotspot.
- If you've run out of your data allowance, I have some on my hotspot you can share.

There are many other ways to say it, but if I were speaking conversationally, I would imply that the hotspot could be used for data instead of explicitly saying "my data...via my hotspot".